# How to approach Supervised Regression Problem of MR image to 256 element vector data?

Tags: regression, neural-networks

I want to train a neural network to predict 256 values as below:

[image]

Inputs are 3D MR images. The dataset contains 20 subjects and their corresponding coil values. Now patch operation will not be possible to augment data since coil values depend on different parts of the brain.

How the 256 real values vary in 20 subjects:
[image]

[image]

from the histogram, it can be seen that out of 256 coils nearly 170 values do not change significantly.

As a beginner, I can say it is supervised regression problem.
**Can these 256 values be predicted using the neural network?**

I am using *ResNet* architecture. More details can be shared if required.

Comment: This needs more details. What are the inputs and what are the desired outputs? Specifically, what do they represent.

Comment: Hey,
Inputs are T1-weighted 3D MR images of human brain/head. For example, take a look at the image https://imgur.com/a/MbO7E7u
So every head/brain will have a target array of 256 coil values as the first picture in the post. The output represent the amout of current required to create a low %RSD uniform magnetization field inside the head. 
and these just are 256 real values of the current. Please let me know if you need anything to clarify.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 20 subjects. For each subject, you have a single MR image plus a single vector of target values. And, the goal is to learn a function that predicts the target vector from the MR image. If that's the case then, yes, this is a regression problem, which is a type of supervised learning. But, with only 20 data points, you will almost certainly *not* be able to successfully fit a complex model like a deep neural net.

Comment: I had some hints about that and my approach was to augment the data for:
1. To create sufficient data samples for the network.
2. The actual image size is 172x220x156 and I am using two fully connected layers in the end of the network ending in 256 output. So my GPU was not able to load.
**How I subsampled:** I created 8 low-resolution images with size 86x110x78 from single images resulting in (20x8) = 160 images. Every 8 images have the same target.
I trained the Resnet3D(calling it!!) with 144 of those images...
Take a look at the training loss curve: https://imgur.com/8tClo1A